# Change where Snapper creates snapshots

Tags: btrfs, snapshot, snapper

I have a BTRFS filesystem, running Arch Linux x86_64. On that filesystem, I have the top level subvolume (id=5), then inside that I have @root, @home, @snapshots, @swapfile. I want to be able to create a Snapper configuration to automatically snapshot @root and @home to @snapshots. The default seems that it will create a subvolume for its snapshots inside the subvolume I create a configuration for, is there any way to change where it creates the snapshots to?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry, but no. `snapper` always creates snapshots within the subvolume it snapshots.

An alternative tool is [btrbk](https://github.com/digint/btrbk). It's configuration allows you to specify where the snapshots are created.

I've been using `btrbk` successfully to create periodic snapshots (triggered with a systemd timer) and also within my backup script to transfer snapshots to an external device, while applying a retention policy.

Answer (score 3):

Well, what I did was :

- mount the Btrfs root volume if not already done (e.g. to `/mnt`)
- create the snapper configs as usual; snapper will create the subvolumes `/.snapshots`, `/home/.snapshots` etc.
- delete these subvolumes and create new ones at the places you like them to be, maybe your Btrfs root (e.g. `/mnt/@SNAPS`, `/mnt/@HOMESNAPS` etc.)
- create empty folders at the locations where snapper created the subvolumes before (`/.snapshots`, `/home/.snapshots`)
- add entries to `/etc/fstab` to have the `/@SNAPS` subvolume mounted to `/.snapshots`, `/@HOMESNAPS` to `/home/.snapshots` etc.

With this setup, snapper does have access to its hardcoded snapshot destinations while they actually reside in direct subvolumes of the Btrfs top-level.

Comment: This is the correct answer.

Comment: This is a related post on archlinux wiki with further details on this topic (with same solution; also contains more general guidance on subvolume layout and configuration, and reasons): https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?id=194491